# Selecting a distinct value from a 1:N dependent on a table connected to N as a 1:1

Tags: sql, ms-access

**Wow that title is a doozy.**

Here's the situation...

I have three tables.

**APPLICATIONS:** The first table is a catalog of applications, these applications contain an application ID, the Application Name, and other fields unimportant to this question.

**INVENTORY:** The second table is a list of deployments of these applications. The deployments contain the application name, application Id, the inventory ID, the division, the facility, and other fields unimportant to this question.

**FRMP:** The third table is a table created whenever an inventory record is created; this table tells us whether or not the inventory records hold confidential information. It contains an application ID, an Inventory ID, an FRMP ID, and a column that determines if the inventory record associated with it contains sensitive data.

**The relations:**
An application can belong to many inventory records, but an inventory record can only have one application. An FRMP record must have only one Inventory record associated to it, but an inventory record can exist without an FRMP record.

Here's what I'm trying to do, and have been struggling to do for the past two days...

**I need a list of every application (by name) where for every record in which it is deployed, not a single one of those deployments contains sensitive data.**

For example, if record 250 in Inventory has application name 74 and FRMP.HoldsSensitive = "No", but record 379 in Inventory has application name 74 and FRMP.HoldsSensitive = "Yes", I don't want to see application 74.

This is NOT as easy as it looks.

**EDIT**

Here is some example data and the preferred output.

```
AppID     AppName   Vendor    
01        FooIt     Goodstuff Inc
02        BarIt     Greatstuff Co
03        SaltIt    Sweet Inc
04        SugarIt   Sweet Inc

InvID     AppName   Division  Facility  
01        FooIt     Corporate Nearville
02        SaltIt    Corporate Farville
03        SaltIt    USA       Sin City
04        SugarIt   USA       Sin City
05        BarIt     USA       Vice City
06        BarIt     USA       Sin City
07        FooIt     USA       Sin City
08        SaltIt    USA       Vice City

FRMPID    INVID     APPID     HoldsSS
01        01        01        Yes
02        02        03        Yes
03        03        03        No
04        05        02        No
05        06        02        No
06        07        01        No
07        08        03        Yes
```

The query should only return BarIt. It should not return SugarIt because SugarIt doesn't exist within the Inventory table.

Comment: It doesn't look hard, but you should edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really post too much example information... The actual database is over 35k records and contains personal information. However, I can provide some sample table input. I can do it tomorrow when I get back to work. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanna retrieve the application names, how 'bout

```
SELECT ApplicationName
FROM APPLICATIONS
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT *
FROM FRMP
WHERE FRMP.ApplicationID = APPLICATIONS.Application_ID
AND FRMP.HoldsSensitive = 'Yes'
)
AND EXISTS
(
SELECT *
FROM INVENTORY
WHERE INVENTORY.Application_ID = APPLICATIONS.Applications_ID
)
```

Comment: While this works at pulling out all application names where sensitive information doesn't exist, this also pulls every application that doesn't have any deployments whatsoever.

Comment: Edited the query so it will only pull records for deployed applications